# Access denied while pushing to ContainerRegistry

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was trying to push the docker image build to the Azure Container registry using the Azure YAML pipeline. But while pushing i am getting an error like

```
 "denied: requested access to the resource is denied
 ##[error]denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  ##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1"
```

Below is the azure yaml pipeline code part i used for this. Also tried by removing the includeSourceTags and additionalImageTags

```
variables:
  BuildConfiguration: "Release"
  AzureSubscription: "ea158397-eb3f-461a-94df-0eb6bbaada60"
  AzureContainerRegistry: "microservicecontainerregistry01.azurecr.io"
  KubernetesServiceEndpoint: "AKSServiceConnection"
  ResourceGroup: "microservicedelivery"

- task: Docker@1
  condition: eq(variables['fullCI'],True)
  displayName: 'Push runtime image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: ${{variables.AzureSubscription}}

    azureContainerRegistry: ${{variables.AzureContainerRegistry}}

    command: 'Push an image'

    imageName: '$(imageName)'

    includeSourceTags: false

    additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
```

Same error is happening in the Microsoft hosted machine as well as with the private machine.

Comment: What you show there is not a valid YAML document, you cannot have both a key (`variables`) - value pair for a mapping and an item indicator (`-`) in the same node (the root level of your YAML document). You are using some other file than the one you presented.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#build-and-push) with the sample YAML snippet to help you push the images to ACR.